# Launching Visual C++ .exe file in Processing

Tags: batch-file, visual-c++, exec, processing, launch

I am trying to run a released .exe file of my Virtual C++ project using Processing. I've tried launch() and exec(), both works for any other .exe file or different file types. I am using Processing reference code for launch().

```
void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw() { 
  // draw() must be present for mousePressed() to work
}

void mousePressed() {
  println("Opening Process_4");
  launch("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Processing\\ProjectFile\\x64\\Release\\ProjectFile.exe");
}
```

I've tried pretty much everthing like changing slashes, moving my Visual C++ file to C: or D:, I even created a batch file (.bat) by using Processing.

```
void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw() { 
  // draw() must be present for mousePressed() to work
}

void mousePressed() {
  PrintWriter output=null;
output = createWriter("myfile.bat");
output.println("cd "+sketchPath("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Processing\\ProjectFile\\x64\\Release"));
output.println("start  ProjectFile.exe");
output.flush();
output.close();  
output=null;
launch(sketchPath("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Processing\\ProjectFile\\x64\\Release")+"myfile.bat");
}
```

No matter what I do, even if the .exe and .bat files work just fine when I double click on them, launch() or exec() do nothing when I use them for the same purpose. I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days, so It would be a great if someone would be able to put me out of my misery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your app 32bit? also alot of missing info, e.g. what  sketchPath() does. exec() and launch() are horribly outdated left-over, use CreateProcess family for WinAPI. Or ISO-based library if your IDE already support that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. I just figured out how to do it so I'll leave the line that worked for me in an aswer here for possible future needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the line that worked for me. I used exec() instead of launch() in the first code I posted.

```
exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c","start","/w", "C:\\Users\\Ozan\\Documents\\Processing\\PlateRecognition\\x64\\Release\\myfile.bat"});
```